# Calculating one-and two-tailed t-tests manually in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test

I have two samples `d1` and `d2`:

```
d1 <- c(18,21,16,22,19,24,17,21,23,18,14,16,16,19,18,20,12,22,15,17)
d2 <- c(22,25,17,24,16,29,20,23,19,20,15,15,18,26,18,24,18,25,19,16)+5
d  <- d2-d1
```

In order to perform a paired two-tail t-test I use the following code on the differences `d`:

```
standard_error <- function(vals){
  return(sd(vals) / sqrt(length(vals)))
}

t_test <- function(d){
  t <- mean(d) / standard_error(d)
  return(2*pt(abs(t), length(d)-1, lower=F))
}
```

This gives me that the p-value is `9.37919e-10`, so quite a significant result. As an alternative I tried using `t.test`-function in R:

```
t.test(d1, d2, paired=T)
```

This gives me the same as above, so everything is OK here.

**However**, now I want to perform a one-tailed t-test for if the mean of `d2` is larger than that of `d1`. Is it correct that I can achieve this by simply returning `pt(abs(t)` in the `t_test`-function above, i.e., divide it by 2?

Comment: @user2974951 As a general rule it can't be correct, because that would never give a p-value above 0.5

Comment: @Glen_b That is a good point. What is the correct (i.e., most general way) to do it?

Comment: [What happens when there's a one-tailed hypothesis test and the results are in the other tail?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164444/what-happens-when-theres-a-one-tailed-hypothesis-test-and-the-results-are-in-th) ... the answer there seems to cover your question so this may in effect be a duplicate